# Can I get Azure Cosmos DB header 'x-ms-request-charge' from fail calls?

Tags: java, rest, azure, header

I am getting this header in response for every successful call to Cosmos DB, but in case of unsuccessful call, I don't get it. Is this by design?

Answer (score 1):

As [Query Documents REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/query-documents#headers-1) for example, you could see that the `x-ms-request-charge` is returned by all Cosmos DB responses.

I tested the rest api in the postman and I get get `x-ms-request-charge` header.

[image]

[image]

So, you just use below code :

```
System.out.println(connection.getHeaderField("x-ms-request-charge"));
```

Comment: Yeah, but when I make call, if it is unsuccessful, I get DocumentClientException, with some headers, but there is no x-ms-request-charge header there.

Comment: @AleksandarGrujic You mean you use sdk?

Comment: Yes, I use sdk. And for all fail calls I am getting that DocumentClientException,which doesn't contain that header. But for .NET it does. I read it on official Microsoft Azure web page. If you have any advice, please post. Thanks.